# Extract text from a file

Tags: vim

I have a file as:

```
<div id="check_1246"> ... </div>
<div id="check_3682"> ... </div>
.....
...
```

I want to extract the numbers after "check_". I seen similar questions on this website. I still can't figure out how can I do this using vim.

Comment: What do you want to do with the number after you extract them out?

Comment: @DJ Nothing, Just trying to play with vim.

Comment: It totally depends on the context what you want to do with it. For example, if you just want to search for numbers after check you can do ":/check_\d+". If you want to do search and replace, then ":%s/check_(\d+)/{what you want to replace here}/"

Comment: @DJ In actual I want to extract this numbers in a new text file.

Comment: You could record a macro. Would be something like this...
qnq (record macro)
f_ (find underscore) l (move right)
return
f" (find quote)
return
SHIFT V d (delete line)
something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could automate the whole thing but for a one off action, easiest would be to

- Copy everything to a new buffer
- Substitute on each line

Following substitution command would do

```
%s/\v^\<div id\="check_(\d+).*$/\1
```

Breakdown

```
%                          : work on the entire buffer
s/                         : start a substitute command
\v                         : use very magic search mode  
^\<div id\="check_(\d+).*$ : search from start of line to end of line. (\d+) captures the number
/\1                        : replace found string with captured number
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a class name in all div and follow following step, see example

```
$( "divclass" ).each(function( index ) {
  var id= $(this).attr('id');      
  var arr = id.split('_');
  res= arr[1];
});
```

variable res contain your id's value in array form.

Comment: Sorry mate, I missed tag. my mistake. :(